# Improve canvas' speed reaction

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have canvas with about 70 polylines that each one has a lot of points. To this canvas I made a `mouse_move` function that dosent have a heavy code but its work really slowly. I tried this with less polylines and its work better. 
Can someone help me with ideas to make the `mouse_move` work better with all originals polylines?
here is how i create every polyline (`nStep` is number around 10000):

```
for (int j = 0; j < nSteps; j++)
            {
                linesCounter++;
                helpString = rayLines[linesCounter].Split(' ');
                p.X = Convert.ToDouble(helpString[1]);
                p.Y = Convert.ToDouble(helpString[2]);
                beam.Add(p);
            }
            plotRay();
```

this is how I plot the polyline to the canvas:

```
private void plotRay()
    {
        double x, y;
        PointCollection fitPoints = new PointCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < nSteps; i++)
        {
            x =  beam[i].X;
            y = beam[i].Y;
            Point p = new Point();
            p.Offset(x, y);
            fitPoints.Add(p);
        }
        Polyline ray = new Polyline();
        ray = setBrush();
        ray.Points = fitPoints;
        Form.workingCanvas.Children.Add(ray);
    }
```

and this is my `mouse_move` method:

```
 public void mouseMove(Point currentPos)
    {
        if (firstUse)
        {
            double currentY = Math.Round((currentPos.Y) / (Yresulotion), 2);
            double currentX = Math.Round((currentPos.X) / (Xresulotion), 2);
            Form.WidthLine.Y1 = currentPos.Y;
            Form.WidthLine.Y2 = currentPos.Y;
            Form.HeightLine.X1 = currentPos.X;
            Form.HeightLine.X2 = currentPos.X;
            Form.DotOnGraph.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Form.DotOnGraph, currentPos.X -     (Form.DotOnGraph.Width / 2));
            Canvas.SetTop(Form.DotOnGraph, currentPos.Y - (Form.DotOnGraph.Height / 2));
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: We can't help you unless we know what you are actually doing. If you have a specific problem or slow point, show us code relevant to that problem, but otherwise, there really isn't a specific question here.

Comment: Instead of rendering your draws from states, if your just trying to re-render the background when doing your user controlled animations, you want to use `var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);` and `canvasContext.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);`. With undo and redo you must use states, but when animating to just get rid of a few lines, your code will have to do too much work.

Comment: @PHPglue The question is about WPF, not HTML.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can understand your problem more specifically.

Comment: I added the relevant code.